# Process JTL logs stage failing with error "groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: jtl for class: java.lang.String"

Tags: jmeter, jenkins-pipeline, performance-testing

Below is the pipeline stage i'm using for processing JTL logs. I'm getting the below error

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: jtl for class: java.lang.String
```

Is this not the format to compare performance testing results from previous build and current build? Thanks!

```
  stage("Process JTL logs") {
   agent {node 'Test_Node'}
     steps {
           sh 'echo "Processing Test logs"'
           /*
           * Use the Performance Plugin to process the .jtl log file.
           */
           perfReport compareBuildPrevious: true, 
           filterRegex: '', 
           ignoreFailedBuilds: true, 
           ignoreUnstableBuilds: true, 
           modeOfThreshold: true,
           relativeFailedThresholdPositive: 80.0, 
           relativeUnstableThresholdPositive: 80.0, 
           sourceDataFiles: "/testFolder/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/output/Report-$BUILD_NUMBER.jtl"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Escape dot as `$BUILD_NUMBER\.jtl"`

Comment: Thank you! For sourceDataFiles I used single quotes '' instead of double quotes "" to resolve this issue.